# NHibernate EventListener to set property null

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a model that looks similar to this:

```
public class Employee {
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
}
```

I have a query like this:

```
var myEmployees = session.Query<Employee>()
                         .Where(a => a.Name.Equals(name)); // name is given as parameter
```

now I have the need to set the `Gender` to null with an NHibernate EventListener. I guess I have to use an IPreLoad or IPostLoad EventListener. But I don't know hot to access the entity.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use `IPostLoad` event and chekc the type of the entity you are loading. But let me ask, why is the reason to do it on the eventListener?

Comment: @FelipeOriani It's because we have an external tool, that has to set some property values to null if a user is not authorized. Can you give me an example with an eventlistener, and maybe how you would do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand something important before using Listeners on NHibernate. It will run over all entities mapped from the `NHibernate` perspective. If you write a bad code on it, it can degrade the performance of your application. Given that, you can define a listener on the `NHibernate` `Configuration` object. You define a class that implements an interface from the NHibernate listeners you want and implement the method. Add an instance of this class into the NHibernate configuration. (I didn't test the code bellow, it's just a draft) For sample:

```
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Event;
using NHibernate.Persister.Entity;

public class EmployeePostLoadListener : IPostLoadEventListener
{
    public virtual void OnPostLoad(PostLoadEvent postloadEvent)
    {
        if (postloadEvent.Entity is Employee)
        {
            var employee = (Employee)postloadEvent.Entity;

            // do what you want with the object
            employee.Gender = null;
        }
    }
}
```

In the configuration of the NHibernate, you can add this listener, something like this:

```
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
cfg.EventListeners.PostLoadEventListeners = new IPostLoadEventListener[] {new EmployeePostLoadListener()};
```

See more about EventListeners and Interceptors on the [documentation](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html).

Comment: One last question, wouldn't it be a `PostLoad` instead of a `PreLoad` Eventlistener?

Comment: Yes, it could be on PostLoad, because the entity was already loaded. I fix my awnser to future users check the right one. :)